# Is it possible to have a TR element that is significantly taller than the TD elements it contains?

Tags: html, css

While refactoring a routine that dynamically creates a table, I find myself pondering a better way to display (what is effectively) a section separator.

The markup created looks similar to this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Column 0</td>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Column 0</td>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">Separator Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Column 0</td>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I think that the `separator` would be better as pure CSS, rather than a separate row (if nothing else, sorting the table becomes far simpler). As such, I would prefer to generate markup more like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Column 0</td>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>
            <td>Column 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Column 0</td>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>
            <td>Column 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="section-start" data-sectionText="Separator Text">
            <td>Column 0</td>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>
            <td>Column 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>...</tfoot>
    <caption />
</table>
```

All of my efforts thus far all look very similar to this instead:

**Current Output**
[image: Current Output]

I've tried several variations on the following style definitions:

```
tr.section-start {
    display: /* literally every valid value according to Chrome Dev Tools */
    flex: /* various values */
    height: 4em;
    max-height: 4em;
    line-height: 1em;
    background-color: #0F0; /* used as a highlighter */
}

tr.section-start::before {
    content: attr(data-section-text);
}

tr.section-start td {
    display: /* literally every valid value according to Chrome Dev Tools */
    flex: /* various values */
    height: 1em;
    max-height: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

The problem is that, regardless of what I try, I cannot get the `tr.section-start` to display how I'd like it to. Here's what I'm trying to do:

**Desired Output**
[image: Desired Ouput]

Assuming what I want to do is possible, how can I style it in CSS to accomplish my goal?

Also, given that I'm reworking the routine that creates the tables and rows, I'm flexible on the markup (if that needs to change), but I'm tasked with bring the page up to Standards, so if markup needs to change, it should be valid HTML5.

Comment: I am not sure what other styles you have but you could give the `td` a thick border of transparent colour, will that work for you?

Comment: if it gets me output that looks like the image labeled **Desired Output**, I'm happy to try it.... I assume an `rgba` color with an alpha of `0` would work to get a transparent border-color?

Comment: I have a solution, but it works if you have only *one* section in the table.  Would that be worth posting?

Comment: @pete you just set `border-top: 20px solid transparent` for the divider row td, this will give you the visual effect of the content is pushed down but if your cell has bg colour it will show thru. Added an answer

Comment: @RickHitchcock by *section*, do you mean only one `tr` with a class of `section-start`? or like only one `tbody`? I need to be able to have multiple rows classed with `section-start` in the `tbody`.

Comment: Figured it out and posted a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these styles:

```
table {
  position: relative;      /* for absolute-positioned pseudo-elements */
}

td {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

tr.section-start::after {  /* use ::after instead of ::before */
  content: attr(data-sectionText);
  position: absolute;      /* positioned based on table */
  left: 0;                 /* stretch from start to */
  right: 0;                /* ... end of the table row */
  line-height: 30px;       /* height of the section text */
  padding: 0 0.5em;        /* maintain cell's padding */
}

.section-start td {
  padding-top: calc(30px + 0.5em);  /* height of the section text + the cell's padding */
}
```

The trick is to use an `::after` pseudo-element.  The `::before` pseudo-element creates a cell at the *beginning* of the row, which you don't want.  Creating it at the end of the row doesn't matter, because you can move it with CSS as needed.

**Snippet:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  position: relative;  /* for absolute-positioned elements */
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
}

tr.section-start::after {  /* use ::after instead of ::before */
  content: attr(data-sectionText);
  position: absolute;      /* positioned based on table */
  left: 0;                 /* stretch from start to */
  right: 0;                /* ... end of the table row */
  line-height: 30px;       /* height of the section text */
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}

.section-start td {
  background: yellow;
  padding-top: calc(30px + 0.5em);  /* height of the section text + some padding */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Column 0</td>
      <td>Column 1</td>
      <td>Column 2</td>
      <td>Column 3</td>
      <td>Column 4</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>Column 0</td>
      <td>Column 1</td>
      <td>Column 2</td>
      <td>Column 3</td>
      <td>Column 4</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr class="section-start" data-sectionText="Separator One">
      <td>Column 0</td>
      <td>Column 1</td>
      <td>Column 2</td>
      <td>Column 3</td>
      <td>Column 4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Column 0</td>
      <td>Column 1</td>
      <td>Column 2</td>
      <td>Column 3</td>
      <td>Column 4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="section-start" data-sectionText="Separator Two">
      <td>Extra text to test width</td>
      <td>Column 1</td>
      <td>Column 2</td>
      <td>Column 3</td>
      <td>Column 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Very close to what I was looking for! Thank you and have an upvote. Is there anyway to prevent the `td` elements in the affected row from stretching vertically to fill the available height? Otherwise the required `border` property makes it look very odd... :)

Comment: After re-checking your snippet (which renders exactly the way I was looking for), I realized the problem was with how I was applying the styles to my actual table... clearly I require more caffeine this morning. Thank you for this answer!

Comment: Whew, was a fun challenge : )

Answer (score 0):

Just make the tr a bigger height:

```
tr.section-start {
    line-height: 5em;
}
```

Then the html:

```
<table>
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="section-start" data-sectionText="Separator Text">
            <td>Column 0</td>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>
            <td>Column 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Column 0</td>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>
            <td>Column 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Column 0</td>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>
            <td>Column 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>...</tfoot>
    <caption />
</table>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2ohNE79VLxTXipJgm2Lo?p=preview)

Comment: This does make the row taller, but the `td` elements stretch to fill the extra height, *regardless* of whether I specify a `line-height` for the `td` elements or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could accomplish it like this... at least this is what I think  you want

Only issue is if you have bg color for the cells then it will show up thru the border

```css
.section-start td {
  border-top: 20px solid transparent
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>...</thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="section-start" data-sectionText="Separator Text">
      <td>Column 0</td>
      <td>Column 1</td>
      <td>Column 2</td>
      <td>Column 3</td>
      <td>Column 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column 0</td>
      <td>Column 1</td>
      <td>Column 2</td>
      <td>Column 3</td>
      <td>Column 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="section-start" data-sectionText="Separator Text">
      <td>Column 0</td>
      <td>Column 1</td>
      <td>Column 2</td>
      <td>Column 3</td>
      <td>Column 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Column 0</td>
      <td>Column 1</td>
      <td>Column 2</td>
      <td>Column 3</td>
      <td>Column 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>...</tfoot>
  <caption />
</table>
```